# Mockito code during @Before annoted method solution

Tags: java, junit4, mockito, xunit

i'm new on using Mockito framework (and Behavior/Test Driven Development) and using
to help me code some things;

I´m coding my own Java library for xml to create graphic things and
i tried first verify some behaviours:
(`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(Class)` is used in `BaseTestClass`):

```
public class GeneralXml extends BaseTestClass {

    private static final String TAG = "General XML";
    @Mock(name="xml") private XmlGraphics mockXML;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{ 

        //stub method parseDimension
        when(mockXML.parseDimension(anyString()))
            .thenReturn(500);

        // stub method parsePosition: 500 X 500 X 500 is an
        // arbitrary dimension of window
        when(mockXML.parsePosition(anyString()))
            .thenReturn(
                new Random().nextFloat() * mockXML.parseDimension(Xml.WIDTH),
                new Random().nextFloat() * mockXML.parseDimension(Xml.HEIGHT),
                new Random().nextFloat() * mockXML.parseDimension(Xml.DEPHT));

        // Now Colors must have betwwen 0 and 255
        // (RGB color)
        when(mockXML.parseColorComponent(anyString()))
            .thenReturn(
                new Random().nextInt(256),    
                new Random().nextInt(256),    
                new Random().nextInt(256));    

    }
```

But I receive error in all subsequent verifications, like:

```
@Test
public void mockPosition() {
    Log.d(TAG, "mock", "x = "+mockXML.parsePosition(Xml.X));
    Log.d(TAG, "mock", "y = "+mockXML.parsePosition(Xml.Y));
    Log.d(TAG, "mock", "z = "+mockXML.parsePosition(Xml.Z));

    verify(mockXML, times(3)).parsePosition(anyString());
}
```

I think that my error is in:

```
 when(mockXML.parsePosition(anyString()))    
        .thenReturn(    
            new Random().nextFloat() * mockXML.parseDimension(Xml.WIDTH),
            new Random().nextFloat() * mockXML.parseDimension(Xml.HEIGHT),
            new Random().nextFloat() * mockXML.parseDimension(Xml.DEPHT));
```

This is not a valid code? or I misunderstanding something?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this as the first line in your setUp() function:

```
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

Comment: I "uninherited" GeneralXml  from BaseTestClass (that itsef have MockitoAnnotation.initMocks(this), and put in setUp(), but not worked to;

Comment: I have following response from JUnit: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at gml.processing.xml.reader.test.GeneralXml.setUp(GeneralXml.java:34)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. although stubbed methods may return mocks, you cannot inline mock creation (mock()) call inside a thenReturn method (see issue 53)

Comment: Ok so its throwing the error because your answering a call to your mock with the mock object being called. It looks like you've misunderstood how Mockito works. You need to test an object by creating it as you would normally 'private XmlGraphics mockXML = new XmlGraphics()' (notice no Mock annotation). You only need to use the Mock annotation if your object requires any dependencies and you need to simulate their behaviour. If you want paste a function from your XmlGraphics class here and I'll show you how to test it.